# Page object practices

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, page-objects

I am building a testing framework for a website using Page Object Model with Selenium

I am thinking that in general if I have two pages with the exact user controls and functions but different URLs I should create one father page class that has two classes inheriting from it. But what if I have the same two pages with different locators for controls? what do you think? do you think that creating a totally separate class for every page will be a good practice? or is there a way to let the children classes override locators? knowing that I am using PageFactory.

Here is an example:

```
public class Header 
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout_button")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }
    public Header()
     {
      PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
     }

    public void Logout()
     {
      this.BtnLogout.Click();
     }
    }

public class Header 
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

   public Header()
    {
     PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

   public void Logout()
   {
    this.BtnLogout.Click();
   }
}
```

Comment: correct you about what?

Comment: Why same page has different locators? What is the thing this locator depend on?

Comment: no, I am assuming that the website has pages with the same content, it is not the same page, different pages with the same content

Comment: So it looks like they provide similar functionality, e.g. function to logout, but implemented differently. Looks like a good place for interfaces. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about C# but in Java annotations are static and cannot be changed at runtime. So this excludes using PageFactory.

However, you could simply use dynamic locators, i.e., old `driver.findElement(locator)` where locator is provided somehow dynamically. This doesn't seem very clear implementation to me. Neither I can see any benefit from that.

More clear solution for me would be to involve interface, e.g.,

```
public interface Header {
   void Logout();
}

public class Header1 implements Header { 

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public Header1() {
      PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

   @Override
   public void Logout() {
    this.BtnLogout.Click();
   }
}

public class Header2 implements Header { 

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout_button")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public Header2() {
      PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

   @Override
   public void Logout() {
    this.BtnLogout.Click();
   }
}
```

And can be used:

```
Header oneHeader = new Header1();
Header anotherHeader = new Header2();
...
oneHeader.Logout();
...
anotherHeader.Logout();
```

Comment: so you are suggesting that I should get rid off the FindsBy annotations ? and not use PageFactory?

Comment: @YahyaHHussein Yes if you see a benefit of using interfaces. It obviously depends on your use case.

Comment: yes, you are right, it depends on the system I am testing, but is getting rid off Pagefactory is a good practice? it is a cheap price to pay to buy more organised architecture? I am thinking about this trade, what do you think?

Comment: @YahyaHHussein I re-thought and think that PageFactory with annotations still can be used. See my update to the answer.

Comment: pardon me, but what benefit will I get from such code? as everything is coded twice, I need a solution where I can write logout body in the father class

Comment: @YahyaHHussein The benefit is that the code that calls `Logout` does not need to know which implementation it is using. I don't see any benefit on creating a hierarchy here: both Header pages are implemented differently (different locators), so similarly both corresponding page objects should be implemented differently. You can push on your developers to use same locators if header is same thing in all the pages.

Comment: actually the header is the same in all the pages, but with different locators, and I can not push the developers to do anything, I am not the boss

Comment: @YahyaHHussein That's off-topic but by pushing I meant negotiating. In my team I am also not a boss but definiting locators/identifiers is part of our common strategy to make the product easy to test (investment in testability). If something is hard to test I go to developers and try to convince them to simplify things for me. It often works :-)

Comment: I am new in the company, so I am working on it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion which doesn't need separate objects. Might be useful if your locators are different because of, let's say, different user roles, and you want to stick with PageFactory.

Use

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Xpath, 
       Using = "@class='logout' or @class='logoutbutton']")] 
public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }
```

Duplicating objects just because you need to change one selector is bad. Unless there is a very good reason for it. You can abstract Header, but it wouldn't change the fact that there is a code duplication.